# serving static content with a cachall route - express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am making a project using MEAN stack, and would like to serve up my files using express. So far, when I load the page only the index file is loaded, but for the other 2 dependencies I get an error like this:

```
GET /assets/styles/css/application.css 404 9.470 ms - 151
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/shooshte/Webpages/Curriculum/assets/views/index.html'
    at Error (native)
```

I tried serving up my files with the express.static method, but it doesn't seem to work. I also want to have a cachall route, that always serves up my index.html file (building an angular app, so angular will handle routing from index).

My server.js file:

```
// packages
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var path = require('path');

//app configuration
    var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

    // body parser
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    //CORS requests
    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST');
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, content-type, Authorization');
        next();
    });

    //log all requests to console
    app.use(morgan('dev'));

app.use(express.static(__dirname +'/assets'));

//catchall route
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/assets/views/index.html'));
});

//start the server
app.listen(port);
console.log('Running on: ' + port);
```

index.html

```
<!doctype HTML>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Miha Šušteršič</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/styles/css/application.css">
</head>
<body>
    <script src="../../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

my file structure looks like this:

```
assets
--scripts
--styles
----css
------application.css
----sass
--views
--index.html
bower_components
node_modules
.gitingnore
bower.json
gulpfile.js
package.json
readme.md
server.js
```

Comment: You are serving index.html from views directory in your catchall route code whereas in your file structure index.html is directly under assets directory ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you specify `app.use(express.static(__dirname +'/assets'));` in your express configuration, it means that express server will look for static files in assets directory. Now in your .html files you should mention static file path without *assets* directory.

So replacing `<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/styles/css/application.css">` with `<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/css/application.css">` should fetch application.css successfully.